# Allow form validation for Symfony 2 File constraint if empty

Tags: file, symfony, validation

I am trying to achieve the following based on this example:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html
I have a virtual filed that is going to be used for uploading a file. Everything works perfect for the upload process. However, the file field in the form is always required probably because of

```
/**
 * @Assert\Image(maxSize="1000000")
 */
public $image_virtual;
```

Is there any way to have a File or Image requirement only when the $image_virtual is filled? I want to be able to save the form even if the user doesn't input an Image

Comment: Do you use Symfony 2.1? Do you get an error when trying to submit the form? Is your form field attribute `required` `false`?

Comment: I use Symfony 2.1.6 and form field is required="required"

Comment: At the formbuilder I added ->add('image_virtual','file',array('required'=>false) and it worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: added my comment as an answer below so people don't need to search in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it should work totally fine like that as long as you don't insert a

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
```

into your entity.

You have to check that your field is not required in your formbuilder, like this:

```
$builder->add('image_virtual', 'file', 
    array(
        'required' => false
    )
);
```